# Secret Manager (describe secret ) Policy and permissions?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I am using describe secret call for AWS secret manager and  i have attached the IAM policy to describe secret but I have given the resource in the policy as * means all the arns . But it is throwing me an error like( is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:DescribeSecret on resource: /dev/ek/test because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:DescribeSecret action) . It is saying me to specify my secret arn in Policy but
Is there any way where i don't need to specify my secret arn , Instead of that I can mention * in policy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Choose all resources instead of Specific ARN, this will allow describe access for all ARNs.
However, ensure there is no explicit Deny for that specific ARN

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But what if the secret that i am passing to describe secret function Invalid or will it return any response or throw an error

Comment: It will get you a 400 response with ResourceNotFoundException